# Error: The server does not support SSL connections - Node.js and PostgreSQL instance in GCP with SSL connection

Tags: node.js, postgresql, windows, ssl, google-cloud-platform

I can't seem to connect my Node.js server to the PostgreSQL instance I have running on Google Cloud SQL, which I've configured to only allow SSL connections.

In the terminal, it says 'The server does not support SSL connections,' which is impossible since I've successfully connected using the same certificates from pgAdmin to the Google Cloud SQL instance.

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express'); // Módulo de express
const app = express(); // Crea una instancia de express
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000; // Puerto del servidor
const { pool } = require('./db'); // Importa el objeto pool desde db.js

// Configura tu servidor aquí, define rutas y controladores
app.get('/', (req, res) => { // Define la ruta '/'
  res.send('¡El servidor está funcionando!'); // Envía una respuesta al cliente
}); 

// Inicia el servidor
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Servidor en funcionamiento en el puerto ${port}`); // Imprime un mensaje en la consola
});
```

**bd.js**

```
const { Pool } = require('pg'); // Módulo para conectarse a la base de datos
const dotenv = require('dotenv'); // Módulo para cargar variables de entorno
const fs = require('fs'); // Módulo para leer archivos

// Carga las variables de entorno desde .env
dotenv.config();

// Configuración de la conexión a la base de datos
const pool = new Pool({
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  ssl: {
    ca: fs.readFileSync('./ssl_files/client-cert.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl_files/client-key.pem'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl_files/server-ca.pem'),
  },
});

// Conexión a la base de datos
pool
  .connect()
  .then((obj) => {
    // Conexión exitosa
    console.log('Conexión a la base de datos establecida');
    obj.done(); // Liberar la conexión
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Error de conexión
    console.error('Error al conectar a la base de datos:', error);
  });
```

**pg_hba.conf**

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     scram-sha-256
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow connections from the local IPv6 address for Node.js
host    all             all             fe80::47a9:6cee:f2cc:274e%5/128  scram-sha-256
```

**Images**

[Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwlOB.png)
[GCP and pgAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMjVt.png)

Comment: Probably one of your connections is going to the wrong db server, probably because it is pointing to a different host than you think it is.

Comment: @jjanes I still can't achieve it, could you help me? What information do you need? The project is blank, and the database as well. I just want to achieve this connection.

Comment: It would be hard to access whether you are using the same host in both places without you showing us the host you are using, which you might not want to make public (but as  long as you use good passwords, I don't see any real harm in it. And it isn't like miscreants aren't constantly port scanning the whole internet anyway).  To make debugging simpler, I'd use psql for both connections, once with PGSSLMODE=disable, and with PGSSLMODE=require.